# What is the correct process for merging hotfix changes into multiple release branches (ie: dev/staging)?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-flow, git-workflow

I'm wondering what is the correct way of getting a hotfix into various main release branches which ensures Git history for these branches are more aligned and Git history is consistent?

I have the following main branches setup:

- release/dev - shared dev team testing environment
- release/staging - QA team testing environment
- release/uat - wider company testing environment
- release/production - production

A developer creates a feature branch (feature/myfeature) from release/dev and then merges it into release/dev. When a 'release' has passed dev testing, release/dev is merged (via PR) into release/staging to allow QA to do testing. Once QA testing passes, release/staging is then merged (via PR) into release/uat to allow the greater company to do final testing. Once it's fully approved, release/uat is merged (via PR) into release/production.

Along each step, hotfixes/bugfixes/changes can be made. I'm using bitbucket, and if a fix is applied to staging/uat/production, I use the 'Sync' button to "sync downwards" the changes into each of the other main release branches.

Example:

1. hotfix/mybug is merged (via PR) into release/production
2. release/production is merged into release/uat via the 'Sync' feature
3. release/uat is merged into release/staging via the 'Sync' feature
4. release/staging is merged into release/development via the 'Sync' feature

The problem I see is that the lower branches start to have more Git history due to the 'syncing' and this makes things appear to be ahead/behind even though they have the same code.

Therefore, I'm wondering if there is a more correct way of getting commits applied at higher up branches (staging/uat/production) into the lower branches which wouldn't cause Git history differences? Such as, should I be PRing the hotfix branch into each of the main release branches instead of only release/production and syncing?

Comment: You have tagged this question "git-flow", but what you describe doesn't sound like [the git-flow branching model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: @IMSoP I can appreciate it's not traditional git flow, but it's very close to it. I have two additional main branches between develop and master (production). We still treat feature, hotfix and bugfix the same way. You could probably consider staging/uat as a sort of 'release' branch, which sticks around.

Comment: I think I would just cherry-pick the fixes to each target branch, ensuring that the new commits properly trace back to the original commit/PR.

Comment: @David Sure, but the root of your problems *is* those extra branches. By that, I don't meean that your workflow is "wrong"; just that the answer from the point of view of git-flow is "don't have those branches", which probably wouldn't be very helpful to you. That also suggests a possible X/Y Problem: the question isn't necessarily "how to merge between these branches", but "what branches and merges would help us achieve these process goals".

Comment: Regarding the tag, I feel that this workflow is in the bureaucratic spirit of Git Flow.

Comment: Assuming that `hotfix/mybug` was branched off of a commit that is already in `release/production` (most likely even its tip), then your procedure is the most correct one. There is nothing more correct than that. There is no problem unless you make one up.

Comment: @IMSoP Okay, so taking the additional branches out of the equation, if I hotfix/bugfix from and back into production, do I then merge production into development or do I PR the hotfix into  development?

Similarly, let's say there is a release branch in the works which I've bugfixed, do I merge the release branch into dev or PR the bugfix's branch into dev?

This is really the root of this topic.

Comment: Git doesn't care. It is a matter of the workflow. You can merge the bugfix branch alone into each integration branch; you can merge the integration branches (like you described in the OP); or you can even merge the bugfix branch alone and then later the integration branches in addition. Whatever suits you best. None of these is wrong from a technical (Git's) point of view.